# how to insert a line within ant build file target range using awk

Tags: perl, sed, awk

i need help about one solution using either awk (preferable), sed or perl.
the solution should be intergarted inside bash shell scripts. Here is my problem,
i need to insert one line inside the target of ant build file target as follows:

```
<target name="-AAAA" unless="non_AAAA_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines
</target>
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
              The line should be inserted here  as <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
</target>
<target name="-BBBB" unless="non_BBBB_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
</target>
many targets here as this is a large file
```

please note that there are many target name in that build.xml file but the `name="XXXX"` is
always unique. the end separator for all other target is same as `</target>`.
please note that the line should be inserted before the line ... `</target>`
please note that build.xml is a lagre file with many targets and word **"name="-XXXX"** is unique but not the word **"-XXXX"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Perl solution: use a flag `$inside` that tells you whether you are inside the desired target:

```
perl -pe ' $inside = 1 if /<target name="-XXXX"/;
           print qq(              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>\n) if $inside and m{</target>};
           $inside = 0 if m{</target>};
         ' 1.xml
```

Or, using [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML) wrapper [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open 1.xml ;
insert chunk { qq(              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>\n) } append //target[@name="-XXXX"] ;
save ;
```

Comment: thnx  following is the code message i have tested `perl -pe ' $inside = 1 if /<target name="-XXXX"/; \
print qq(              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>\n) if $inside and m{</target>}; \ and following is the error message i have encountered Can't modify single ref constructor in scalar assignment at -e line 3, near "0 if"
syntax error at -e line 4, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
$inside = 0 if m{</target>}; \
' build.xml1`

Comment: @NilAkash: Try putting everything in the quotes to a single line.

Comment: thnx, putting everything in a single quoto did solved the problem. i works now, hi FY for you..could pls explain how did you tracked the end match and how did it workded, its not important to answer but will be helpful..

Comment: @NilAkash: I process the file line by line (the `-p` switch). Once I match the beginning of the right target, I set $inside to 1. On leaving target, I set it back to zero. If I am inside the right target and match the end tag, I add a new line with the desired content.

Comment: there is little bit problem, the line was inserted before  the last line of </target> but within another target name sucs as <target name="-BBBB" which also has same end tag </target> but which appears only after the name-"XXXX", could you please correct the code..the code is wokring but missing the inserting on the dedired line...btw perl -pe can't save in the same file but i have to redirect it withing perl -pe 'bla bla' build.xml > build.xml2, it that correct?

Comment: @NilAkash: Can targets be nested? Is the formatting always as shown here? Please, show the part of the XML that does not play well with the code.

Comment: thnx, it was my mistake, the code works perfectly..thnx a lot

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed`:

Content of `infile`:

```
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              ...............
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>
              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>  **###The line should be inserted here**
</target>
<target name="-YYYY" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              ...............
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>
              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>  **###The line should be inserted here**
</target>
```

Content of `script.sed`:

```
/^<target[ \t]\+name="-XXXX"/,/^<\/target>/ {
        /^<\/target>/ { i\
Your line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        }
}
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

With following output:

```
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">                                                                                                                                                                                         
              <antcall target="init"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              ...............                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>  **###The line should be inserted here**                                                                                                                                                              
Your line                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
</target>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<target name="-YYYY" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">                                                                                                                                                                                         
              <antcall target="init"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              ...............                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>  **###The line should be inserted here**                                                                                                                                                              
</target>
```

Comment: thnx  i can't use your code because i have to use that code withing a bash script and the file build.xml should be modified inside bash script. so i can't use script.sed file. could you please modify your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with `sed` utility:

```
sed -i -e '/-XXXX/,/<\/target>/s/<\/target>/NEWLINEINSERTEDHERE\n<\/target>/' infile
```

we tell `sed` to consider only the right `<target>...</target>` part of the file, then we substitute `</target>` with your added line and  `</target>`

Comment: thnx, i have used following code `sed -e '/name="-XXXX"/,/<\/target>/s/<\/target>/<antcall target="ZZZZ"/>\n<\/target>/' build.xml1 > build.xml2`, i can't use -i option because it is not supported, i get the following error message: **sed: Function /name="-XXXX"/,/<\/target>/s/<\/target>/<antcall target="ZZZZ"/>\n<\/target>/ cannot be parsed **

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with `awk`: set the record separator to `</target>` and you're anchored in the right place:

```
awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' '
{ print }
/name="-XXXX"/ { print "              INSERTED LINE", "\n" }
{ print RT }'
```

Should do what you need. The output record and field separators should be empty to get the whitespace correct.

#### Update

Example running the above script on the new data:

**build.xml**

```xml
<target name="-AAAA" unless="non_AAAA_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines
</target>
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
              The line should be inserted here  as <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
</target>
<target name="-BBBB" unless="non_BBBB_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
</target>
many targets here as this is a large file
```

Run script:

```
awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' '
{ print }
/name="-XXXX"/ { print "\t\t<antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>", "\n" }
{ print RT }' build.xml > out.tmp
```

Note that you need to escape the double quotes. Note also that if you want tabs in front of the added line, add the appropriate amount to the `print` statement.

**out.tmp**

```
<target name="-AAAA" unless="non_AAAA_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines
</target>
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
              The line should be inserted here  as <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
</target>
<target name="-BBBB" unless="non_BBBB_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              many antcall lines here
</target>
many targets here as this is a large file
```

Verify the addition:

```
diff build.xml out.tmp
```

Output:

```diff
8a9                        
> <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
```

### Edit

Here's a more portable version of the script:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="</target>"; ORS=""; OFS="" }
{ print }
/name="-XXXX"/ { print "\t\t<antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>", "\n" }
{ print RS }' build.xml > out.tmp
```

Comment: thnx, i have used you solution as code `awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' ' \
{ print } \
/name="-XXXX"/ { print "              <antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>, "\n" } \
{ print RT }' build.xml1`  but i do get the foolowing error messages **awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' ' \
{ print } \
/name="-XXXX"/ { print "              <antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>, "\n" } \
{ print RT }' build.xml1 ** Could you please see what's went wrong..

Comment: Can't see the error you're referring to, paste mistake? Could you add what you've tried and the error to the question, marking it as an edit or update.

Comment: thnx, Here is the error message: syntax error The source line is 3.
 The error context is
                /name="-XXXX"/ { print "              <antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>, >>>  "\ <<< n" } \
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 3.

Comment: Looks to be due to the backslashes (\\) you've added, try using it exactly as listed.

Comment: thnx, here is the error again as you suggested  code `awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' '
> { print }
> /name="-XXXX"/ { print "              <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>,"\n" }
> { print RT }' build.xml1`
 syntax error The source line is 3.
 The error context is
                /name="-XXXX"/ { print "              <antcall >>>  target="ZZZZ"/>,"\ <<< n" }
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 3.  the same problem

Comment: thnx, now your code works but it has not the same effect as i hoped, now the string in appended as the first line after the search result, and the second line loosed the tab spaced as a result. and the code removes the character "<" from all the line of the big build.xml file. target line look at here target name="-XXXX" unless="non_BSCS_buildpackage">
                <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
antcall target="init"/>   the code i have used for this is as you suggested. the code ``

Comment: It's very hard to see what you're doing as the comments cannot contain newlines. Could you, as I suggested, add the code you're using and the failing input to you're question?

Comment: thnx Thor, i have updated the example and here is the code which i had used as you suggested `awk -v RS='</target>' -v ORS='' -v OFS='' ';{ print };/name="-XXXX"/ { print " <antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>","\n" };{ print RT }' build.xml1 > build.xml2`

Comment: thnx for your brief solution, it works, i have tested it with my personal fedora (linux) terminal but it does not work with aix5.x (IBM) server. the same problem as described before..i am also trying to figure out the problem, its absolutely not your code probem,i will take the solution as accepted..

Comment: Use `gawk` if you can. I've added version of the script at the bottom of the answer that should work in other versions of `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> cat temp
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>
</target>
```

an awk solution:

```
> awk '{if($0~/\/target/){p="\t<antcall target=\"ZZZZ\"/>\n"$0;print p}else print}' temp
<target name="-XXXX" unless="non_XXXX_buildpackage">
              <antcall target="init"/>
              <antcall target="YYYY"/>
        <antcall target="ZZZZ"/>
</target>
```

Comment: thnx, i can't cat because the target name="-XXXX" is too long and there are many antcall line before word </target>. could you please make the awk code more dynamic, the solution cant be used in a tmp file first. but i cant save the whole large build.xml file and then again rename it. i will wait..